# Multi-packet transmissions over USB CDC - Increasing speed

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2022

I'm designing a project to test and program a small custom PCB, using an STM32F4 microcontroller.

The programmer is based on an STM32F429 Discovery board, with a 16MByte flash on a carrier PCB.

Communication between the programmer and PC is a terminal style interface over a USB CDC (Virtual COM Port) interface.

I tried implementing ZMODEM over the top of the terminal, but it seems that the terminal program I'm using on the PC doesn't quite follow the rules as I expected, so I ended up creating my own transfer protocol. Initially tried a packet size of around 2KBytes, but I hit a 64 byte limit (presumably packet limit for USB2 FS). Reduced the packet size to 64 bytes to get reliable transfers, but at only 177 bytes / second overall transfer speed. Not great. So started trying things to improve the transfer speed.

To try and make it faster, I put a loop in the PC to transmit each 2K data block in 64 byte chunks, expecting to see the RX interrupt on the STM32 fire repeatedly, and load each data chunk into the RX buffer, for later processing as a complete frame.

This doesn't happen - The embedded is just sat there waiting for data, and nothing after the first chunk arrives.

I don't think it's embedded side where the issue is, as if I restart the PC side, it will immediately start receiving data again when the PC starts the new session.

I've heard that perhaps the USBSER.SYS driver is buggy, but surely it can't be this buggy?

Is there an expert out there on CDC communication that might be able to assist?